# LLVM set target to WebAssembly

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, webassembly

I've coded a fronted in C++ to exploit LLVM core in order to get a PHP file and generate an IR for a classical architecture. I'm able to run this code with embedded JIT compiler of LLVM.
I would produce an IR to WebAssembly. I'm using LLVM 6.0 with WebAssembly as target built

```
$ llvm-config --targets-built
AArch64 AMDGPU ARM BPF Hexagon Lanai Mips MSP430 NVPTX PowerPC Sparc SystemZ X86 XCore WebAssembly AVR
```

I've set this update in my code

```
...
LLVMSetTarget((LLVMOpaqueModule *)context->module, "wasm32");
...
```

Now I noticed that dupmed IR code is identical with or without my code edit, and I've followed this pipeline to generate my wasm file

```
$ llc -asm-verbose=false -march=wasm32 -o my.s my.bc
$ binaryen/bin/s2wasm my.s > my.wast
$ wabt/bin/wat2wasm my.wast -o my.wasm
```

But when I run

```
$ node ./runwasm.js my.wasm main
```

I get the following error

`RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds`

I can't understand where is the problem because if I follow this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/yurydelendik/4eeff8248aeb14ce763e), I will not get any error.

Suggestions?